# Curl works fine but Perl LWP failed to post Unicode code to HTTPS server

Tags: perl, curl, unicode, https, lwp

My snippet as below, using curl I can send the Unicode string to the server
and after push notify the message to my mobile phone, displayed correctly the Chinese characters on the phone.

```
      curl  "https://oapi.dingtalk.com/robot/send?access_token=$ACCESS_TOKEN" \
   -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
   -d '{"msgtype": "text", "text": {
        "content": "\u6d4b\u8bd5",
     }}'
```

But when I use the Perl LWP library to send the same content to the server,
I only got 6d4b8bd5 displayed on the app.
I've tried to use tcpdump to compare the difference between curl and LWP sent out buffer, but as it's https server it's not working.

```
    #!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use warnings;
use Cpanel::JSON::XS qw( encode_json );
# Create a user agent object
use LWP::UserAgent;
$ENV{PERL_LWP_SSL_VERIFY_HOSTNAME} = 0;

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
$ua->agent("curl/7.47.0");


# Create a request
my $req = HTTP::Request->new(POST => 'https://oapi.dingtalk.com/robot/send?access_token=bf47148ea6a1b125395f9313873ac508');

$req->content_type('application/json;charset=utf-8');

my $var='\u6d4b\u8bd5';

my $message = encode_json({ msgtype => "text", text => { content => $var } });

$req->content($message);

# Pass request to the user agent and get a response back
my $res = $ua->request($req);

# Check the outcome of the response
if ($res->is_success) {
  print $res->content;
} else {
  print $res->status_line, "n";
}
```

any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Earlier, you didn't encode. Now, you double encode. `encode_json` is already handling the encoding to JSON, so don't do it manually too!

If you provide the 12 characters `\u6d4b\u8bd5`, it will receive the 12 characters `\u6d4b\u8bd5`.

If you provide the two characters U+6D4B and U+8BD5, it will receive the two characters U+6D4B and U+8BD5.

- `my $var = chr(0x6D4B) . chr(0x8BD5);`
- `my $var = "\x{6D4B}\x{8BD5}";`
- `my $var = "\N{U+6D4B}\N{U+8BD5}";`
- `use utf8; my $var = "测试";`
- etc

Comment: Thanks! So it means that encode_json api cannot support using the \u6d4b\u8bd5 format and must use the format you mentioned above. If I want to stick to \u6d4b\u8bd5, then I have to find another way to pass the variable in the inner json value.

Comment: Any suggestion to work with \u6d4b\u8bd5 string format  as it's the database format ? use  --trace-ascii /dev/stdout with curl I can see that curl is sending out "content": "\u6d4b\u8bd5" to the https server.

Comment: If you checked the output of your code (with my change), you'd also see `\u6d4b\u8bd5` within the output. Again, let `encode_json` handle the JSON encoding!

Comment: If you have `\u6d4b\u8bd5` in the database, you've done something wrong. You shouldn't see `\u6d4b\u8bd5` outside of JSON. Maybe you did some shoddy manual parsing instead of using `decode_json` or similar? (Of course, if the database field contains proper JSON, then just `decode_json` or similar as the first step of getting the value you want.)

Comment: \u6d4b\u8bd5 is from another REST api, for example, 182383:\u6d4b\u8bd5,182384:\u7a4b\u2bd5,etc, the list is available from the website. Then I save the list in local JSON array and use the number key to find its value and send it to my backend server, which will push to the registered app.

Comment: What's your point? Are you claiming `decode_json` or similar was used somewhere in that process? If not, what I said still stands.